# Show $f$ concave, $C^2$ implies $f''\leq 0$

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, finite-differences

Suppose I wanted to show that a concave function $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ which is $C^2$ must have negative second derivative at each $x\in (a,b)$. I might try this by finite difference, noting that if $f''(x)>0$, then $$\frac{f(x + \Delta x)+f(x-\Delta x)-2f(x)}{2(\Delta x)^2}$$

should be positive for small $\Delta x$, contradicting concavity.

Can you recommend another method for showing this besides finite difference? Is there a problem with my (admittedly sketchy) proof?

Comment: Second derivative non-negative means convex. Second derivative non-positive means concave. You mixed something up. ["means" in the sense of "implies"]

Comment: You forgot the title.

Comment: I think you want to have a weak inequality in the title, otherwise the function $f$ given by $f(x) = -x^4$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{f(x + \Delta x)+f(x-\Delta x)-2f(x)}{2(\Delta x)^2} \le 0$$

The definition of concavity is that the value at the midpoint of any interval is less-than-or-equal-to the average of the values at the endpoints of the interval.  $x$ is your midpoint, $x +\Delta x$ and $x - \Delta x$ are your endpoints.

By definition, $\frac {f(x + \Delta x)+f(x-\Delta x)} 2 \le f(x)$ which implies $f(x + \Delta x)+f(x-\Delta x) \le 2 f(x)$.

$$\frac{\text{some non-positive number}}{\text{some positive number}} \le 0$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually wasn't looking for a more detailed version of the finite difference proof; I was looking for other proofs.

Comment: Ah I was showing that your proof wasn't contracting concavity.  The only other approach that comes to mind might be using something like jensen's inequality, but it wouldn't be simpler.

Comment: My proof was trying to contradict the assumption that $f''>0$.